# question about spatial velocity in the book <modern robotics>

Tags: kinematics, screw-theory

[image]

I think the equation(3.73) should be:

$\dot p-w_s$x$p=\dot p-\dot p=0$

have no idea how it can be wrong

and don't know the difference between infinitely large body and a body just include the fix-frame origin and body-frame origin

Comment: They are choosing to rewrite $\nu_s$ so you can see the idea of the infinitely large body in the equation. It's a valid way to write the equation, so not wrong. Are you asking why $\dot{p} \neq \omega_s \times p$ instead?

Comment: @hauptmech thanks. yes i m asking why $\dot p≠w_s×p $ instead.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, E Takly. Great first question! I'm looking forwards to an answer on this - questions like this, and the difficulty I had in trying to conceptually understand the physical meaning of spatial maths, are exactly why I wound up walking away from this approach to dynamics. I'm hoping a really good answer to this question might be enough to get something to click for me, too.

Comment: @Chuck ha, me too,really want to give up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A coordinate transformation of a point P from Frame 1 to Frame 0 is given by:
$$
\mathbf{p}^0=\mathbf{o}^0_1+\mathbf{R}^0_1\mathbf{p}^1.
$$
Differentiating with respect to time gives:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{p}}^0=\dot{\mathbf{o}}^0_1+\mathbf{R}^0_1\dot{\mathbf{p}}^1+\dot{\mathbf{R}}^0_1\mathbf{p}^1.
$$
Considering that $\dot{\mathbf{p}}^1=0$ as $\mathbf{p}^1$ is *fixed* in Frame 1, we come up with:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{p}}^0=\dot{\mathbf{o}}^0_1+\mathbf{S}\left(\mathbf{\omega}^0_1\right)\mathbf{R}^0_1\mathbf{p}^1,
$$
being $\mathbf{S}$ the *skew* matrix. This expression can be further reduced noting that $\mathbf{R}^0_1\mathbf{p}^1=\mathbf{r}^0_1$:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{p}}^0=\dot{\mathbf{o}}^0_1+\mathbf{\omega}^0_1 \times \mathbf{r}^0_1,
$$
which is eventually the known form of the **velocity composition rule**.

To come back to your statement, $\dot{\mathbf{p}}^0=\mathbf{\omega}^0_1 \times \mathbf{r}^0_1$ holds only when $\dot{\mathbf{o}}^0_1=0$, that is when there exists a pure rotational velocity without translational velocity.

This result can be obtained also by observing that a vector $\mathbf{p}$ can be expressed in terms of its magnitude $p$ and unit vector $\mathbf{\hat{p}}$ as:
$$
\mathbf{p}=p \cdot \mathbf{\hat{p}}.
$$
Thereby, the time derivative is:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{p}}=\dot{p}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{p}}+p\cdot\dot{\mathbf{\hat{p}}}=\dot{p}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{p}}+\mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{p}.
$$
Only in case there is a pure rotational velocity (i.e. $\dot{p}=0$), then you'll get:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{p}}=\mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{p}.
$$

Comment: The steps from $\dot{\mathbf{R}}^0_1\mathbf{p}^1$ to $\mathbf{S}\left(\mathbf{\omega}^0_1\right)\mathbf{R}^0_1\mathbf{p}^1$ are shown in the [angular velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Rigid_body_considerations) wikipedia article.

[Murray, Li, and Sastry](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf) remains my favorite explainer of robot maths and page 51-52 shows the steps as well.

Comment: legend, thank you. didn't notice the translation.so the equation(3.73) becomes: $\dot{\mathbf{p}}-\mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{p}=$$
 \dot{p}\cdot\hat{p}+p\cdot\dot{\hat{p}} -\mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{p}=\dot{p}\cdot\hat{p}+\mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{p} = \dot{p}\cdot\hat{p}.
$ is it right?

Comment: @E Takly, you are right.